# Can't make sense of these Functions

Tags: javascript, function

```
//iterator(value, key, collection)
  _.each = function(collection, iterator) { //takes in collection of values and a functino called iterator
    if(Array.isArray(collection)) { //if collection is array, proceed
      for (var key = 0; key < collection.length; key++) { //iterates over the length of collection
        iterator(collection[key], key, collection);//plugs in individual element value, index of element, and array var
      }
    } else {
      for (var objKey in collection) {
        iterator(collection[objKey], objKey, collection);
      }
    }
  };

  _.indexOf = function(array, target){
    var result = -1; //set result to -1

    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
      if (item === target && result === -1) {
        result = index;
      }
    });

    return result;
  };
//example of input
  _.indexOf = function([1, 2, 3], 2)
```

I can't make sense of these functions.Specifically where _.each function is being used inside of the ._indexOf variable assignment. In the line of code where ._each(array, function(item, index) is executed. Are the results of that function then used to plug into the function of function(item, index) or is it the other way around? How does it know what item & index parameters are for that variable?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for Lodash? https://lodash.com/docs

Comment: What part of that should I be looking at specifically?

Comment: For example, the `.each` function: https://lodash.com/docs#forEach (`.each` is an alias for `.forEach`). It says that it *"Iterates over elements of collection and invokes iteratee for each element. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: `(value, index|key, collection)`. Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false."* Which means that the function is called for every element of the array with the arguments `value`, `index`, and the original `collection`.

Comment: That I understand. But .each = function(collection, iterator) but I don't get how this line works "_.each(array, function(item, index)". Isnt this essentially function(collection,iterator(array,function(item,index))).